# java get response from PayU api poland

Tags: java, jsp, curl, payu

I'm trying to integrate payu poland payment system to my website but cant get success response. Website done by jsp. Here is link that payu gave for help [click](http://docs.payu21.apiary.io/#introduction/integration-flow) im using "create a new order" for configuration. But its not retrieving any answer. Could anywane help me? Here is my jsp code:

```
 `public static String sendPostRequest2(String requestUrl, String payload, String x, String y) {
    StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
            writer.write(payload);
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty(x, y);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(line);
                jsonString.append("<br>\n");
            }
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is;
            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                is = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonString.append(line);
                    jsonString.append("<br>\n");
                }
            }
            jsonString.append(new RuntimeException(e.getMessage()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            jsonString.append(new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage()));
            Logger.getLogger(PayU.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            jsonString.append(new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage()));
            Logger.getLogger(PayU.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return jsonString.toString();
}
public static String get() {
    String x = "";
    String payload2 = "{  'notifyUrl': 'https://your.eshop.com/notify',  'customerIp': '127.0.0.1',  'merchantPosId': '145227',  'description': 'RTV market',  'currencyCode': 'PLN',  'totalAmount': '21000',  'products': [    {      'name': 'Wireless mouse',      'unitPrice': '15000',      'quantity': '1'    },    {      'name': 'HDMI cable',      'unitPrice': '6000',      'quantity': '1'    }  ]}";
    String requestUrl2 = "https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders/";
    x += sendPostRequest2(requestUrl2, payload2, "Authorization", "Bearer 3e5cac39-7e38-4139-8fd6-30adc06a61bd");

    return x;
}`
```

Comment: first look: why did You concatenate JSON and not use any proven library? Many subtle errors can occur. For example tag `<br>` in JSON seems strange

Comment: cuz with curl i get proper answer to get tokens but with library it didnt worked at all

Comment: I think (personal opinion) WE non-native-english should use shorter sentences with correct punctuation. I can't understand You with precision required to design software

Comment: I'm just using no framework and in the page example showed for maven. So I tried to use those libraries for maven but it didnt worked so I decided to use curl

Comment: this is not 'CURL' library, and this is not C or PHP, code doesn't keep any sensible pattern java / object / http/ json (algorithm in catch???) without understandable relation to Payu docs. Your explanations don't get problem forward. Look chaotic copy and paste. I can't help You

Answer (score 0):

set the redirect turn off after that you will get the json response. So in your java code set redirect false.
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);